# FindAllAsync returns empty, USB devices in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, interface, usb, winusb

I am communicating (or attempting to) with an ESP 301 motor controller via USB. [See here for documentation if needed](http://assets.newport.com/webDocuments-EN/images/ESP301_User_manual.PDF) (PDF)

In order to do this, I am working in C# and have the following function:

```
private async void connectDevice()
{
    string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(Constants.ESPVENDORID,Constants.ESPPRODUCTID);
    Console.WriteLine(aqs);
    var myDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
    Console.WriteLine(myDevices.Count);
    try
    {
        esp301 = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(myDevices[0].Id);
        Console.WriteLine("SUCCESSFULLY OPENED DEVICE FOR COMMUNICATION");
        initialized = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR:");
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message.ToString());
    }

}
```

However, the `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs)` call returns an empty container.

I have modified the app manifest to contain the following:

```
<Capabilities>
    <DeviceCapability Name="usb">
      <Device Id="vidpid:104D3001">
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
  </Capabilities>
```

This is the bit that I am most uncertain of, and I am struggling to find much information about this.

In a separate constants class, I have the following defined:

```
public static Guid ESPGUID { get { return new Guid("{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"); } }
public static uint ESPVENDORID { get { return 0x104D; } }
public static uint ESPPRODUCTID { get { return 0x3001; } }
```

which all seems correct, and I have verified the vendor and product ids using the USB View application distributed by Microsoft:

[image: USB View]

Adjusting the `UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector` call to use the GUID defined in the constants file like so:

```
string aqs = UsbDevice.GetDeviceSelector(Constants.ESPGUID);
```

does not seem to change anything either.

I know that the container is empty because the count that I am printing out to the console is 0, and also I get an out of range exception.

The aqs string that I am printing looks like so:

> System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{DEE824EF-729B-4A0E-9C14-B7117D33A817}"
>   AND
>   System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
>   AND
>   System.DeviceInterface.WinUsb.DeviceInterfaceClasses:~="{4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}"

I have tried to provide as much information as possible, any help that you can provide will be appreciated. Thank you.